# SQL Server 2K backup failing as bak files is used by another process

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our backup job failed with error The operating system returned the error '32(The process cannot access the file (XXX_DB.bak) because it is being used by another process.)'. What amuses me is when the SQL Server is creating a new .bak file, how it is possible to be used by another process? There is no anti-virus/tape backup running during this period. Please help me understand how it possible by a process to access this .bak file during the backup operation?

Job details:
Step 1: Deletes old backups
Step 2: performs backup operation

Comment: We need more information as this can be a lot of things. How does your backup job look? What does it do specifically? Is the backup file itself okay, it just cannot be moved or is it the actual backing up process that fails? Are you sure it's a new bak file it's creating and not appending? etc.

Comment: Job does Step1: Deletes old backup file Step2: takes backup. Step1 got succeeded and failed in step 2 only for 1 database out of 5. Now the job is running fine but this happened last month also.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Please find my response above